# Error creating bean with name 'rabbitTemplate' - CloudAMQP with Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-rabbit, cloudamqp

So I want to create a simple queue where I just send data every time I send a text message into it.

I'm using CloudAMQP, their documentation gives me a Java code to use, which does work when running on its own, the issue comes when I add Spring Boot to the mix, this is the class:

```java
public class CloudAMQPService {

    private final static String QUEUE_NAME = "HEREGOESQUEUENAME";

    public void sendMessage(String message) throws Exception {
        String uri = System.getenv("CLOUDAMQP_URL");
        if (uri == null) uri = "HEREGOESURL";
        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        factory.setUri(uri);
        factory.setConnectionTimeout(30000);
        Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
        Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

        channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, false, false, false, null);
        channel.basicPublish("", QUEUE_NAME, null, message.getBytes());
        System.out.println(" [x] Sent '" + message + "'");
        channel.close();
        connection.close();
    }
}
```

I can actually send the message when running it on a framework free Java application,  but if I try to call it using Spring Boot I get this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rabbitTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/amqp/RabbitAutoConfiguration$RabbitTemplateConfiguration.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2]
at 

org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:570) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:845) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:744) [spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:391) [spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) [spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1204) [spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at pe.edu.upc.integracion.IntegracionApplication.main(IntegracionApplication.java:28) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:507) ~[spring-core-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:367) ~[spring-core-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.buildPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:432) ~[spring-orm-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:406) ~[spring-orm-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:333) ~[spring-orm-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1077) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:567) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/rabbitmq/client/ConfirmCallback
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:489) ~[spring-core-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.rabbitmq.client.ConfirmCallback
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    ... 30 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Tried adding the restTemplate as an autowired on the class but to no avail, it still gives me an error, not sure what is going on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to show the full stack trace when asking questions like this; never truncate a stack trace.

Boot assumes you are using Spring AMQP, which is Spring's abstraction over the RabbitMQ client. Either disable Boot's auto configuration (see the boot documentation) or use Spring AMQP instead of the client directly.

Finally, opening and closing a connection and channel for each send is rather expensive.

Spring AMQP caches the connection and channels for you. See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.1.10.RELEASE/reference/html/).

Comment: Alright sorry, I added the rest of the error to the log, disabling the configuration did indeed work for my needs though, thanks a lot!

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.rabbitmq.client.ConfirmCallback` That is an odd root cause since that class is in the `amqp-client` jar.